# (Eclipse) How do I package third party plugins with my feature?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

MyFeature consists of plugins a, b and c which depend on a third-party plugin d. How do I package MyFeature such that

1. It contains d and can install it if it doesn't exist in the target workbench
2. My plugins a, b and c can refer to a specific version of d even if higher or lower versions exist in the workbench
3. The dependency requirements of d be met if it is about to be installed

P.S. I realize some of the above may not be possible. I am just stating my current problem as I see it and if there's a better way that I am completely missing

Answer (score 3):

All what you need is easily done. Your a,b,c plugins can depend on exact version of d. Eclipse plugin development tools allow you to set this.

Plugin 'd' should be on your update site, next to your plugins. Your feature should explicitely declare that it consist of a, b, c and d. If 'd' needs more plugins, it would be best if you also provide them on your update site (and your feature can then include them too).

PDEBuild (ant scripts for headless building of eclipse plugins) supports extracting/repackaging of 3rd party plugins, so you can use this to prepare your feature.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this? like what do you mean by "should be on your update site, next to your plugins"? My feature is installed from an archive, not an install site. I am finding that if I include a third party plugin in my feature, when I try to install that feature and the Eclipse instance already has that third-party plugin installed, the installation fails (Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency).

Comment: Conflicting dependency may mean that eclipse has given plugin in version X, but your feature requires different version. Maybe you can use version X too?

Comment: Yes, thats what I was thinking. Do you know how I can declare that any version of the plugin is valid in my feature manifest (feature.xml)?

Comment: @wildabeast: Can't you just include plugin dependency without specifying a version? http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/feature_editor/dependencies.htm

Comment: @wildabeast: if you're including the plugin as part of your feature (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/feature_editor/plugins.htm) you're declaring version in of plugin included, not a dependency. If your plugins need another plugin, but you don't want to have it in your feature, declare dependency instead.

Comment: Thanks for the continued suggestions Peter. Ok, so if I declare it as a dependency, that solves the problem for the case where Eclipse already has the third party plugin. But what if Eclipse doesn't already have the plugin? I still need to include the third party plugin in my feature so that it can be installed if necessary, how can I do this without declaring it as part of the feature?

Comment: @wildabeast: I'm running out of ideas :-( It sounds like what you want to achieve should be easy, but I'm not sure how I would specify it in feature.xml. One thing that comes to mind is to include plugin 'd' in optional feature that user may or may not to select to install. Another possibility (not sure if that would work) is to specify additional update site for plugin 'd' (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/feature_manifest.html for details about feature.xml)

Comment: haha yes it seems like it should be easy but I just can't seem to find the right configuration. but thanks for the suggestions, I'll post it if I get it.